# How to unencode HTML code in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I have a number of strings that have various HTML encoded characters such as `&#39;`, `&amp;` etc. Is there a way to convert these into plain character strings other than a bunch of `str.replace(/&#39;/g, "'")` type statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without direct access to the DOM (and its parser), you'll need to either install a package to do this for you or write one yourself to do all those `str.replace(/&#39;/g, "'")` type statements.

It looks like there are some good ones on npm:

- https://npmjs.org/package/ent
- https://npmjs.org/package/html-entities